# Check that a cell is being actively edited or the user is typing in the formua bar

Tags: excel, vba

So the idea is:

I have a macro say (for demonstration purposes):

```
Sub test_routine()

    Dim cell As Range
    
    Range("test_range").ClearContents
    
    For Each cell In Range("test_range")
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
        cell.Value = "input"
    Next
    
End Sub
```

the moment I try to edit a cell or select the formula bar, the macro stops working.

Is there a way to stop the execution of the macro while the user is typing something?

This does not work and it does not solve the problem if I directly start typing (after clicking on the cell or in the formula bar) without double clicking on the cell:

```
Public cell_active As Range

Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Do While Target = cell_active
        DoEvents
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Set cell_active = Target
End Sub
```

Comment: If you use `Application.Ontime` instead of `Wait` then the process will be suspended if you enter edit mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `OnTime`.  For example:

```vb
Sub start()
    update
End Sub

Sub update()
    Static cellNum As Long 'track value between calls
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A1:A10")
        If cellNum = 0 Then  'starting off...
            .Value = ""
            cellNum = 1
        End If
        
        .Cells(cellNum).Value = Now
        If cellNum < .Cells.Count Then
            cellNum = cellNum + 1
            'schedule the next run
            Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2), "update"
        Else
            cellNum = 0 'at end of range: reset
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

If you run `start` and then go into edit mode, the updates will suspend until you exit edit mode.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. The thing is, what I am currently trying to accomplish is more complicated than the example case in the code I provided. My macro has actually other macros and it is a nightmare to track every step in each macro and imho would not make any sense. Do you think the method you provided would work in my case?

Comment: I don’t think there’s any way for me to know what’s the best approach here, without all your code there’s no way to test.